# Why new activity is opening when notification clicked?

Tags: android

I can see my group of notification on notification bar; fired from Firebase and I want to implement Expandable view of notifications. I am using [This link](https://medium.com/exploring-android/android-n-introducing-upgraded-notifications-d4dd98a7ca92)

but I can't implement this because when I click to notifications it open my activity
This is my ShowNotification() method

```
private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
}
```

And here is code for Notification Builder

```
 MyFirebaseMessagingService.notificationMessages.add(message);
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
   //         .setCustomContentView(remoteViews)
   //         .setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)
            .setContentInfo("" + (MyFirebaseMessagingService.notificationMessages.size()))
            .setGroup(GROUP_KEY);
```

please suggest me Any intent.Flag or other code so that I can stop activity to be opened on notification click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the below line:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

And pass 0 instead of intent:

```
notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, 0);
```

Comment: thanks for the rpl but i cant pass null because that intent is handled in other methods also so it'l generate NullPointer

Comment: I've used Androidhive's code but i edit that code in my wayI am posting my showNotification() here

Comment: please check this link because its really long code i can't post it
https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: @nidhi  Sorry nidhi I can't check the whole link as it's very time consuming i can help you out on specific part of the code that's why i told you to have a discussion on hangout